# Errors in linux header files when building a program

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, gcc, header

Hello i have a problem when i build a program.
I simply type 'make' but i get a lot of errors from headers files.
Like unknown variable types.

For example:

**'size_t' undeclared did you mean 'ssize_t' ?**

**unknown type name '__gnuc_va_list' did you mean '_IO_va_list'?**

I tried to reinstall linux headers, I changed variable types (i know is better not to change system files), included header files but nothing

My laptop has been built with ubuntu, maybe i missed some steps after the installation?

Comment: Or maybe your software doesn't compile for that kernel version?

Comment: It might be, but it just list the supported operating systems like GNU/Linux and FreeBsd. It doesn' t refer to any kernel version.

Comment: How old is it? The success rate tends to decrease with time.

Comment: The software, of course, assuming you have a fairly recent jernel version. But to be more precise, the time gap between them it's what matters. Not a general rule, it depends on many factors.

Comment: The softwate is called Radamsa, it' s a fuzzer which basically test the security of other softwares. It' s used a lot in the security field, so i think it's well maintained.

Comment: Please, add the code into the question post. This is how Stack Overflow works. See also [ask].

Comment: IF you are trying to compile software not written by yourself, you have to figure out how to configure this software to use the correct header files on your system. Often this is done running something like `./configure`, but there are other ways. Only you know what you have installed and what it looks like. Often there's a file called `INSTALL` that tells you what to do.